# url link validation using python

Tags: python-2.7

## This is the function responsible for finding which links are working and which are not. But this function always returns False value

```
def link_status_checker(url):
    print url

    try:
        f = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url))
        deadLinkFound = True
        print deadLinkFound
    except:
        deadLinkFound = False
        print deadLinkFound
```

the url's that I am trying to check are as follows

```
url=["http://91mobiles.com/samsung-galaxy-a9-pro-price-in-india","http://91mobiles.com/samsung-galaxy-j7-2016-price-in-india","http://91mobiles.com/samsung-galaxy-j7-prime-price-in-india"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the url string as an argument to urllib2.urlopen() and in the code handling exception, check for the error code 'urllib2.HTTPError' which when raised means the url is not valid.